# How to display a Popup above mouse location?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, contextmenu

I have a `DataGrid` control in my application in which I added a custom-defined `Popup` for some actions.
The basic thing is: I have a matrix of `double` numbers displayed in a `DataGrid`. Right clicking on selected cells will make a popup appear, in which the user can type a value then press enter to shift the values selected (all of the values selected will be incremented with the value entered)

Here is the current behavior:

[image: Shift popup]

And the XAML code for the popup:

```
<Style x:Key="ShiftPopupStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
    <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="StaysOpen" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" Value="Fade" />
    <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Mouse" />
    <Setter Property="Child">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Border BorderBrush="Navy" Background="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding ShiftValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="30" Margin="4" >
                        <TextBox.InputBindings>
                            <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ShiftCommand}" Key="Enter" />
                        </TextBox.InputBindings>
                    </TextBox>
                    <Button Content="Shift" Margin="0,4,0,4"
                            Command="{Binding ShiftCommand}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here is how I open the `Popup`, this method is located in my custom `DataGrid` (I use a custom `DataGrid` able to display values from a 2D Array):

```
protected override void OnMouseRightButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsReadOnly)
    {
        this.shiftPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }
    base.OnMouseRightButtonUp(e);
}
```

Now, I need to add a `ContextMenu` to my `DataGrid`. When I try to add a `ContextMenu` directly on the `DataGrid`, I can see it before the grid is initialized, but afterwards, only the `Popup` shows up. No `ContextMenu` at all.
I was expecting them to be at the same location, but the `ContextMenu` just won't appear.

Ideally what I'd need is an Office-like `ContextMenu`:

[image: Office popup]

In which my shift Popup would appear above the mouse pointer, and my `ContextMenu` at the usual position.

If needed, I wouldn't care having a fixed layout (layout above/contextmenu under, whatever the mouse position is).

Would you have any idea on how to do so?

Alternatively, I was thinking about including the `Popup` content in the contextMenu, hoping it won't end up being ugly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to manually open the ContextMenu by setting it's IsOpen property to true. Also, try looking into StaysOpen property if it helps you somehow: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.staysopen.aspx

Comment: Already worked on it, the Popup works fine so far, the only problem I have with this Popup is to set its position above Mouse position (it is under the mouse position by default). ContextMenu appears to be some sort of "overriden" by the Popup here, probably due to the override on MouseRightButtonUp :/

Comment: did you try setting it's Placement property? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.placement.aspx

Comment: Yes, it's in the XAML code I posted: `<Setter Property="Placement" Value="Mouse" />`

Comment: I mean did you try different values? Here is an article that can help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613596.aspx

Comment: Yes I did, as you can read on the article, `PlacementRectangle` is ignored when you set the target to `Mouse` or `MousePoint`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to override default `ContextMenu` template.

Result:

[image]

Add reference to `PresentationFramework.Aero.dll` and try this code:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" 
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MenuStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContextMenu}}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <theme:SystemDropShadowChrome Name="Shdw2" Color="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding ShiftValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                 Width="30" Margin="4">
                                            <TextBox.InputBindings>
                                                <KeyBinding Command="{Binding ShiftCommand}" Key="Enter" />
                                            </TextBox.InputBindings>
                                        </TextBox>
                                        <Button Content="Shift" Margin="0,4,0,4" Command="{Binding ShiftCommand}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </theme:SystemDropShadowChrome>

                            <theme:SystemDropShadowChrome Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <Border Name="ContextMenuBorder"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="#F1F1F1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="28" Margin="2"
                                                   RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" />
                                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1" Margin="30,2,0,2"
                                                   Fill="#E2E3E3" />
                                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1" Margin="31,2,0,2" Fill="White" />


                                        <ScrollViewer Name="ContextMenuScrollViewer" CanContentScroll="true"
                                                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="1,0"
                                                      Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}, ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer}}">
                                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                                <Canvas Height="0" Width="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                        VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                                    <Rectangle
                                                        Height="{Binding ElementName=ContextMenuBorder,Path=ActualHeight}"
                                                        Width="{Binding ElementName=ContextMenuBorder,Path=ActualWidth}"
                                                        Fill="{Binding ElementName=ContextMenuBorder,Path=Background}" />
                                                </Canvas>
                                                <ItemsPresenter Name="ItemsPresenter"
                                                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"
                                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </theme:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Shdw" Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,5" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Shdw" Property="Color" Value="#71000000" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Shdw2" Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,5" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Shdw2" Property="Color" Value="#71000000" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource MenuStyle}">
                    <MenuItem Header="Item 1"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Item 2"></MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem Header="Item 3"></MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>

            <System:String>One</System:String>
            <System:String>Two</System:String>
            <System:String>Three</System:String>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you sir. This is TRULY awesome!!! Not exactly what I needed (so I still have my "Popup above mouse?" question pending) but I don't care, this works like a charm!! Thanks again!